# Google Drive appDataScope permission not edit

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have Google drive integration in my Flutter project. My customer wants the following option removed from the OAuth consent request screen.

> "see create and delete its own configuration data in your google drive"

How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `drive.appdata` scope is the one that is displaying that.

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata  See, create, and delete its own configuration data in your Google Drive

Just remove that scope and it will no longer appear.

A side effect will then be that your application no longer will have access to *`See, create, and delete its own configuration data on the users Google drive account`*.